# global variable in GUI netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to declare a global variable in netbeans GUI. Where and how do I declare it? I tried declaring it the public class

```
public class Area extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Area
     */
    public Area() {
        initComponents();
        int ch;
    }
```

But on intializing it later it says no variable recognized.

Comment: You declare "ch" within your constructor thus it's only available within your constructor. To make the variable global you need to declared outside of your constructor.

Comment: You are confusing local variable (here ch is local to the Area constructor) and instance variables

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the purpose of your "ch" variable, but probably you would want to use a static variable.

```
public class Area extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static int yourVar; 
}
```

It doesn't matter how many `Area`s you have eventually, "ch" will always have the same value and can be accessed via

```
 int i = Area.yourvar;
```

You may omit the static keyword, however each Area will have its own value of "ch". In that case, you can access "ch" only via an instance of Area like this

```
Area area = new Area();
area.ch = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable ch to outside the constructor

```
private int ch;
public Area() {
    initComponents();
}
```